# return text from asmx file using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services, asmx

I can't see the problem in working of this simple code

```
setdata.asmx
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
 [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class setdata : System.Web.Services.WebService {

public setdata () {

    //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
    //InitializeComponent(); 
}

[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld() {
    return "Hello World";
}

}

my jquery
$.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "setdata.asmx/HelloWorld",
            contentType: "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
            //data: { category: category },
            success: function (txt) {
                alert(txt);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
          alert("Error:"+jqXHR + textStatus + errorThrown);
        }
        });
```

the error is:

```
[object Object]errorInternal Server Error
```

how can i resolve it

I made a guess of the problem:-
    The jquery is inside the default.aspx page in admin folder of my website named web1
    and i am posting the url simply setdata.asmx ,
    does the server look for setdata.asmx in current directory of root directory

Comment: use F12 or fiddler to see the response coming from server

Comment: If you put breakpoint to your webmethod, does it hit the breakpoint?

Comment: @nilesh thakkar -> it doesn't hit the breakpoint

Comment: @devesh-> i don't know that method , do i have to press f12 when and why?

Comment: If u r using IE 9 10 or chrome , click F12 it open developer tool and help you to see the response in network tab http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589512(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @devesh-> theresponse is   500 internal server error

Comment: Try to generate the wsdl for your webserive YOURSERVER/setdata.asmx/HelloWorld?WSDL and see if you can call it. One more guess change the method to GET and see

Comment: So default.aspx and setdata.asmx are in different folder?

Comment: its a bit complecated, the aspx page from where i am calling jquery is in admin folder in root directory, and the asmx.cs is in appcode folder and asmx itself is in root directory.

Comment: I updated my answer to resolve correct service path. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the jQuery script to check the error:

```
 $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "<%= this.ResolveUrl("~/setdata.asmx")%>/HelloWorld",
        contentType: "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
        //data: { category: category },
        success: function (txt) {
            alert(txt);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Error:" + jqXHR + textStatus + errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

This should simplify debugging.
Aldo use the `ResolveUrl` method to get the correct address for the service.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you've added necessary web.config entries to call asmx service from client script. Check below URL:

http://encosia.com/asmx-scriptservice-mistakes-installation-and-configuration/

Comment: i am using asp.net version 4 , there is no assembly for that in the link

Comment: 3.5+ – As of .NET 3.5, System.Web.Extensions ships with the framework. No additional assemblies need be installed. Just make sure you've those web.config entries and you hit the break point. For error check, web browser console by pressing F12. For FF make sure you've installed Firebug plugin.

Comment: do you have those entries in your web.config file as mentioned in the blog post from the link I provided?